# DX12- hlsl code invoking

Tags: directx

I am pretty new to graphics programming using DX12. I was testing out my skills by building a shader to add 2 buffers and put the result in an output buffer. I have written this code in "ComputeShader.hlsl" however when i tried to invoke it using the following, i get an error sayin "file not found"

ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile(GetAssetFullPath(L"ComputeShader.hlsl").c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, "main", "cs_5_0", compileFlags, 0, &computeShader_madhu, nullptr));

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you have problems in D3dcompilefromfile. I would suggest you to print the return of GetAssetFullPath and verify if It has the expected file location.

Comment: More info:
when i printed the debug error it says the following:
D3D12GetDebugInterface: This method requires the D3D12 SDK Layers for Windows 10, but they are not present on the system.

would this mean something?

Comment: You dont have directx sdk properly installed or dont have It linked correctly on the binaries of your program. You should check the linker setup in your compilation routine.

Comment: But then the NbodyGravity sample runs perfectly well. If the SDk was not properly configured, how is that possible?

Comment: If the sample is running, then you should check if your program is linked with the same libraries as the sample.

Comment: Yes, all i am doing is adding code to the same sample. i am not deleting or changing any path as such

Comment: Next time you want to add more information to your question, you should use the "edit" link instead of posting a whole new question.